# openlayer with mapquest number limit of transactions?

Tags: limits, mapquest

I'm using Open Layer v3 with MapQuest as a map, I'm asking about the limits of request per day ? 
In case there are a fixed limit, can you suggest me another solution with no limit.
Thanks for reaching back with me, as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

All access to MapQuest tiles should be through the MapQuest sdks. There is no OpenLayer plugin for MapQuest tiles.